# How to resolve 500 internal server error in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I was trying to launch Jupiter notebook through anaconda-navigator
But I do not know why I keep getting the 500: internal server error!
I have tried every thing suggested by geeks on Stack-overflow and none of them was able to resolve my issue.
That’s why I am linking the error I get in my terminal(MacOS) window:

```
I was trying to launch Jupiter notebook through anaconda-navigator
```

But I do not know why I keep getting the 500: internal server error!
I have tried every thing suggested by geeks on Stack-overflow and none of them was able to resolve my issue.
That’s why I am linking the error I get in my terminal(MacOS) window:

```
[E 10:57:38.860 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/Desktop/Option%20chain%20live%20data/Option%20Chain%20live%20data.ipynb (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8889', method='GET', uri='/notebooks/Desktop/Option%20chain%20live%20data/Option%20Chain%20live%20data.ipynb', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 775, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 95, in get
    self.write(self.render_template('notebook.html',
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 516, in render_template
    return template.render(**ns)
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "page.html" %}
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/page.html", line 154, in top-level template code
    {% block header %}
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 115, in block "header"
    {% for exporter in get_frontend_exporters() %}
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 40, in get_frontend_exporters
    for name in get_export_names():
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 146, in get_export_names
    e = get_exporter(exporter_name)(config=config)
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 103, in get_exporter
    if getattr(exporter(config=config), 'enabled', True):
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 332, in __init__
    super().__init__(config=config, **kw)
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 118, in __init__
    self._init_preprocessors()
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 499, in _init_preprocessors
    conf = self._get_conf()
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 519, in _get_conf
    if conf_path.exists():
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1424, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "/Users/Anuj/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1232, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json'
```

[E 10:57:38.870 NotebookApp] {
"Host": "localhost:8889",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Sec-Ch-Ua": "".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"",
"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
"Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": ""macOS"",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
"Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
"Referer": "http://localhost:8889/tree/Desktop/Option%20chain%20live%20data",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
"Cookie": "_xsrf=2|e7dfbca5|1f47088ba99d18e833f752efed8d327f|1659242133; username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1659245073|23:username-localhost-8888|44:Y2ZiMzc4YjZiNzk5NGI3MWE4YjBhNzUxMmQzYzNiNTk=|295822d2fe2c733ed69900517af1fd238945c20524cc4db4d5a867632f284ce4"; username-localhost-8889="2|1:0|10:1659245253|23:username-localhost-8889|44:YTU2ODhmZjE1YjgyNDBm

Comment: The error was "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json'". Read https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1594

and try 

chmod -R 777 /usr/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/
chmod -R 777 /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading jupyter works for me

```
 sudo pip3 install --upgrade jupyter
```